# Youtube API Error - Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to load the newest 5 videos to a carousel-like player. When I try to switch between videos I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined

It is happening because it cannot find the `video.stopVideo()` function from the YouTube API. This only happens when I try to load the videos by the API because when I try it with manually input videos, it works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(
    "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
      part: 'snippet',
      channelId: 'WC8s9GnPV_Ol-G9YKvxs4r-w',
      maxResults: 5,
      order: 'date',
      key: 'HIzaSyD8Fjhg8G-Q5xfQQUxyzJc_ikNSe4hK9SD'
    }, function(data) {
      var output;
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item);
        videoTitle = item.id.videoId;
        output = '<iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoTitle + '?ecver=2&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>';
        let currentSlot = '#slide' + (i + 1);
        $(currentSlot).append(output);
      })
    }
  );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var pos = 0,
    slides = $('.slide'),
    numOfSlides = slides.length;

  function nextSlide() {
    slides[pos].video.stopVideo();
    console.log(slides[pos]);
    slides.eq(pos).animate({
      left: '-100%'
    }, 500);
    pos = (pos >= numOfSlides - 1 ? 0 : ++pos);
    slides.eq(pos).css({
      left: '100%'
    }).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 500);
  }

  function previousSlide() {
    slides[pos].video.stopVideo();
    console.log(slides[pos]);
    slides.eq(pos).animate({
      left: '100%'
    }, 500);
    pos = (pos == 0 ? numOfSlides - 1 : --pos);
    slides.eq(pos).css({
      left: '-100%'
    }).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 500);
  }

  $('.left').click(previousSlide);
  $('.right').click(nextSlide);
})

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  $('.slide').each(function(index, slide) {
    // Get the `.video` element inside each `.slide`
    var iframe = $(slide).find('.video')[0];
    slide.video = new YT.Player(iframe);
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}


/* Additionnal styles */

.video-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em;
  background: #444;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide:first-child {
  left: 0;
}

.video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.slide-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  color: grey;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 45%;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .2;
}

.slide-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-arrow:after {
  content: "\003c";
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.slide-arrow.right:after {
  content: "\003e";
}

.slide-arrow.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide3"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide4"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide5"></div>
  <div class="slide-arrow left"></div>
  <div class="slide-arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is because `video` is not a property of a jQuery object, so calling `stopVideo()` on that empty property causes the error. What are you expecting `video` to return? Are you using another library which adds that property which hasn't been included in your question?

Comment: I am expecting it to stop the video before sliding to the next video, calling the YT.Player.stopVideo function. Its works normally when I input the videos manually in the div classes, but it doesn't work when I populated the classes by Youtube's API.